# UIViewcontroller in UIViewController which exceeds the bounds

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` having two parts:

- a `UIView`
- a bar having multiple drop down menus arranged horizontally and having thumbnail images at the top

Because second part is little complex I've decided it to be a `UIViewController` but now I have some concerns:

- Because I have drop down menu, menu will exceeds the bounds of the bar. How can I handle it?
- Is it a good way to have a `UIViewController` inside a `UIViewController`?
- How can I implement a drop down menu? As far I know IOS doesn't have drop down menus.

Answer (score 1):

To use a controller within another controller, you employ a custom container view controller.

- See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) section of the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.*
- Also see the appropriate [Implementing a Container Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) section of the *UIViewController Class Reference.*
- Also refer to the WWDC 2011 video, [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)
- In iOS 6, you can set up storyboards with container views that automatically employ embed segues, saving you from needing to explicitly call `addChildViewController` and the like, if you're using storyboards. Check out the "container view" object in Interface Builder. If you're going to be changing the child controller, you'll have to employ the API referred to in the above links, but for the configuration of the first child, you can set that up in Interface Builder in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, setting up a controller containment could be the right way. The only limitation is that it works for iOS 5 and greater.

Here, what you have to do:

```
// add as child VC
[self addChildViewController:_barViewController];

// add it to container view, calls willMoveToParentViewController for us
[_containerView addSubview:_barViewController.view];

// notify it that move is done
[_barViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Here, you can find additional info [Containing ViewControllers](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/). Obviosly Apple doc is your friend. In addition, if you search for "uiviewcontroller containment" you can find a lot of tuts out there.

If your app needs to target devices where iOS 5 is not the minimum, you should rely on a `UIViewController` and two different views.

Answer (score 0):

About drop down menus, in my opinion they don't work so well with touch interfaces. There are some alternatives, for example an instance of the [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807) class. Here you can read Apple UI design guidelines about segmented controls: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1. If you explain a little bit more about your desired UI functionality we could offer you a better alternative from the user experience point of view.

If you insist with drop down menus, there are some third party control libraries available out there; for example: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/